# Specialization of template variable (for template template class)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, template-specialization, variable-templates

When I try specialize a template variable for a generic container (e.g. `std::list<...>`, and not for an specific one, e.g. `std::list<double>`) I get a link error with `gcc 5.3` (but not with `clang 3.5`)

```
/tmp/ccvxFv3R.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccvxFv3R.s:206: Error: symbol `_ZL9separator' is already defined
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38f68c782d385bac

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<forward_list>
#include<vector>

template<typename T> std::string const separator = ", ";
template<typename... Ts> std::string const separator<std::list<Ts...>        > = "<->";
template<typename... Ts> std::string const separator<std::forward_list<Ts...>> = "->";

int main(){

    std::cout << separator<std::vector<double>> << '\n';
    std::cout << separator<std::list<double>> << '\n';
    std::cout << separator<std::forward_list<double>> << '\n';

}
```

(This compiles well with `clang 3.5` and works as expected. Also the variadic template is not what causes the problem, I tried with a non-variadic template).

If this is not a bug in `gcc`, do you think is there a work around? I tried to use class specialization but it is not possible either:

```
template<class T>
struct separator{
    static std::string const value;
};
template<class T>
std::string const separator<T>::value = ", ";
template<typename... Ts>
std::string const separator<std::list<Ts...>>::value = "<->";
template<typename... Ts>
std::string const sep<std::forward_list<Ts...>>::value = "->";
```

Comment: I think GCC's handling of variable template partial specializations is just broken. Class templates are more mature, but you have to partially specialize the whole thing, which is annoying.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, I ended up doing that, very annoying. Thanks.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69515

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with `gcc`. Workaround (use class templates), like @T.C. suggested.

```
template<class T>
struct sep{
    static const std::string value;
};
template<class T>
const std::string sep<T>::value = ", ";

template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::list<Ts...>>{
    static const std::string value;
};
template<typename... Ts>
const std::string sep<std::list<Ts...>>::value = "<->";

template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::forward_list<Ts...>>{
    static const std::string value;
};
template<typename... Ts>
const std::string sep<std::forward_list<Ts...>>::value = "->";
```

And later a template variable (so to have the same interface)

```
template<typename T> std::string const separator = sep<T>::value;
```

This works in both `gcc` and `clang`.

---

Or also suggested by @T.C., use a static function member instead of a static member (less code)

```
template<class T>
struct sep{
    static std::string value(){return ", ";}
};
template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::list<Ts...>>{
    static std::string value(){return "<->";}
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::forward_list<Ts...>>{
    static std::string value(){return "->";}
};
...
template<typename T> std::string const separator = sep<T>::value();
```

---

Or use `constexpr const char*`

```
template<class T>
struct sep{static constexpr const char* value = ", ";};

template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::list<Ts...>>{static constexpr const char* value = "<->";};

template<typename... Ts>
struct sep<std::forward_list<Ts...>>{static constexpr const char* value = "->";};
...
template<typename T> std::string const separator = sep<T>::value;
```

I tried to use `const_str` (a `constexpr`-friendly version of `std::string`) but I got strange linker errors.

Comment: At this point you might as well just use a static member function instead of a static data member. (Or use a `static constexpr const char*`; both remove the need for an out-of-line definition.)

Comment: @T.C., good point. I added that to my answer. It is less code. I don't understand why `const static` members cannot be defined inline (in-class), after all even (non-static) members can be defined inline nowadays. (`constexpr std::string` is not a possibility). That feature would made the static member more attractive.